# Ipython not showing underscores

Tags: ipython

I am using ipython2.3.0 on debian jessie.

My problem is in the title: The underscores are completely invisible, not displayed, but existing and behaving as expected.

Comment: In the notebook, the terminal, or the Qt console?

Comment: Ok i am sorry, I solved the problem. It was in a terminal but open with the command: "xterm -fa 'Monospace' -fs 12 -e ipython --pylab &"; which surely imply the problem

Comment: OK; I'm not sure how that causes the problem, but I'm glad you solved it. Consider answering your own question - it might help someone else in the future who has a similar issue.

Comment: Yes, please answer your own question.